# How to convert a list containing an even number of floats into a string divided by lists whose size is half of that even number?

Tags: python, string, list

Say you have this list of floats assuming we have an even number of entries :

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

How could one turn this into this string :

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0][4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

If we had 10 elements we would have :

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0][6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
```

etc.

I tried :

```
list_to_str = ' '.join([str(e) for e in total_list])
final_str = '[' + list_to_str + ']'
```

But with this, the first `'['` and the last `']'` are placed only at the beginning and at the end of the string... the middle ones are missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
total_list = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]

str(total_list[:len(total_list)//2]) + str(total_list[len(total_list)//2:])

#'[1.0, 2.0, 3.0][4.0, 5.0, 6.0]'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try list-comprehension

```py
' '.join(map(str, [total_list[i: i+len(total_list)//2] for i in range(0, len(total_list), len(total_list)//2)]))
```

```
'[1.0, 2.0, 3.0] [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this.

```
yourLst = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0] 
middle = len(yourLst)//2
lsts = [yourLst[:middle],yourLst[middle:]]
yourString = ''.join(str(lst) for lst in lsts)
```

output

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0][4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

and for those who crave one line code,

```
yourLst = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0] 
yourString = ''.join(str(lst) for lst in [yourLst[:len(yourLst)//2],yourLst[len(yourLst)//2:]])
```